Use of `by` on first line of lean proof - when to / when not to?
The following lean4 proof generates no warnings or errors.
import Mathlib.Tactic

example {a: ℕ} (h1: a = 4) : a > 1 := by
  calc
    a = 4 := by rw [h1]
    _ > 1 := by norm_num

Removing the by at the end of the first proof line also causes no errors or warnings.
import Mathlib.Tactic

example {a: %$\mathbb{{N}}$%} (h1: a = 4) : a > 1 :=
  calc
    a = 4 := by rw [h1]
    _ > 1 := by norm_num

So my question is - when should by be used and why is it apparently optional here?
Some have suggested that you can move the by to the next line. This isn't my question.
Is there a valid reason for := not being followed by by?
What would be wrong in teaching students to always use by after := ?

Welcom to PA.SE!  I voted to close this since I think it is answered in another question (message above).  See the answer there about there being both a calc term and a calc tactic so you can do this both with and without by.
